# Babel is trying to import a module that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, babeljs, laravel-mix

My compiled Babel output tries to import a function/file that does not exist. Am I missing a configuration or step in my Mix/Babel/Webpack configuration that would output this file?

I am using Laravel Mix (5.0.4) with its default configurations.

I've recently used the Javascript `await` operator for the first time. It is causing an issue with Babel. When Babel processes `await` to make it backwards compatible, it adds `import _regeneratorRuntime from "@babel/runtime/regenerator";` to the beginning of the Javascript file. However, `babel/runtime/regenerator` doesn't actually exist. This causes the Javascript to fail when the browser attempts to load it, producing the error `Error resolving module specifier: @babel/runtime/regenerator`.

I am beyond my understanding of how Mix, Babel, and Webpack work together. I do not know how to tell Mix/Babel/Webpack to produce file(s) that contain the necessary module(s), or if there's something else I need to be doing.

I've tried many solutions via googling, played with the configuration files, and hit my head against my desk a bunch of times. None of these worked. I'm not sure if I am even asking the right questions.

**Debugging info:**

`webpack.mix.js` looks like this:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

// Use of mix.babel() is imperative as this is legacy code and cannot leverage mix.js()
mix.babel('public/js/helpers.js', 'public/js/processed/helpers.js')
  .babel('public/js/main.js',     'public/js/processed/main.js')
  .babel('public/js/stripe.js',   'public/js/processed/stripe.js');
```

The problematic Javascript looks like this:

```
function foo() {
    const bar = document.getElementById('bar');

    bar.addEventListener('click', async (event) => {
        // ('async' is the part which causes the `import` to be added)
    });
}
```

And when run through Babel, looks like this:

```
import _regeneratorRuntime from"@babel/runtime/regenerator";function asyncGeneratorStep(n,e,r,t,o,a,u){try{var c=n[a](u),i=c.value}catch(n){return void r(n)}c.done?e(i):Promise.resolve(i).then(t,o)}function _asyncToGenerator(n){return function(){var e=this,r=arguments;return new Promise(function(t,o){var a=n.apply(e,r);function u(n){asyncGeneratorStep(a,t,o,u,c,"next",n)}function c(n){asyncGeneratorStep(a,t,o,u,c,"throw",n)}u(void 0)})}}function foo(){document.getElementById("bar").addEventListener("click",function(){var n=_asyncToGenerator(_regeneratorRuntime.mark(function n(e){return _regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function(n){for(;;)switch(n.prev=n.next){case 0:case"end":return n.stop()}},n)}));return function(e){return n.apply(this,arguments)}}())}
```

When I dig into Mix's [default Babel config](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/blob/73d0fa424221602de251379e382209186fdbda22/src/BabelConfig.js#L34), I think it's using this:

```
{
    cacheDirectory: true,
    presets: [
        [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
                modules: false,
                forceAllTransforms: true
            }
        ]
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
        [
            '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
            {
                helpers: false
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: In your node_modules folder, is there an @babel directory, and in that is there a runtime directory? There should be. Also, have you tried running `npm install`?

Comment: @M-N `node_modules\@babel\runtime\regenerator` has one file named `index.js`. I've done `npm install`. Also wiped out the directory and reinstalled. Tried adding various libraries for Babel as a matter of trial and error with no success. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: Odd. Your code transpiles fine for me. Maybe try deleting your `node_modules` and running a clean `npm install`. Do you have a `.babelrc` file? (You shouldn't need one, but if you did have one, it might be influencing things). Or anything odd in your `package.json`?

Comment: Update Nodejs to latest version:https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and try again.

Comment: @M-N I've deleted it a few times and installed fresh. I'll play around with it some more. If it works for you, that's good to know. Probably something simple that is misconfigured. I recently upgraded everything to the latest versions. Maybe I missed something. When you load your webpage, where does the actual imported code exist?

Comment: @user8555937 Node and npm are at the latest versions. (12.18.0, 6.14.5)

Comment: Probably laravel-mix attempt to reload the module from a non-global scope. Try js mixin instead; check my answer

Comment: @M-N did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue, @babel/runtime/regenerator/index.js is present

node 15.1 npm 7.0.8 laravel-mix 5.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Use js mixin instead:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('public/js/helpers.js', 'public/js/processed/helpers.js')
   .js('public/js/main.js',    'public/js/processed/main.js')
   .js('public/js/stripe.js',  'public/js/processed/stripe.js');
```

Comment: I need Babel to make the code backwards compatible though. Doesn't this just completely omit Babel?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like `.js()` transpiles it to ES2015. I didn't realize it did this. Thought I had to use `.babel()` for that functionality. Perhaps I've been using it unnecessarily all this time. I will test this out and upvote/confirm your answer once I'm sure everything works. https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/mixjs

Comment: If it doesn't, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54234778/cannot-find-module-babel-runtime-regenerator-import-locally-vs-import-from-npm

Comment: Yeah, I had gone through that answer and a number of other ones. Doesn't seem that the issue is with missing modules (I tried a _lot_ of different modules). So far it looks like using `mix.js()` will allow me to get around/solve the problem. Once I'm confident in the solution I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It appears that using `mix.js()` would solve the problem in most circumstances, but unfortunately the legacy project I am working on needs to retain `mix.babel()`. `mix.js()` adds a number of Webpack compilation features that cannot be toggled off and will break the legacy code. Unfortunate!

Comment: @Lemmings19 did you solve this? I have a nightmare legacy project complaining too...

Comment: @Angelo I ultimately just avoided running the problematic javascript through Babel. I put it in its own Javascript file and didn't run Babel on that one file lol. I tried everything else I could think of before that though... upgraded various libraries, tried different tools/processes, always running into a brick wall eventually. So I just went all the way back to square one, set the offending code to the side, and then carried on as if I hadn't spent several days trying to fix it. XD

Comment: Literally ended up like this: `mix.babel('public/js/stripe.js', 'public/js/processed/stripe.js').copy('public/js/stripeUnminified.js', 'public/js/processed/stripeUnminified.js')` ... oh well. In the end, having backwards compatibility for JS on that one function isn't a huge deal.

Answer (score 0):

**I was not able to find a working solution in a reasonable time for the legacy project I was working on, so I just used a workaround and documented it.** I tried various solutions, different libraries and compilers, upgrading existing libraries, better workarounds and so on. Because this was a legacy project, most changes/updates/tool swaps resulted in a cascade of changes needed (and it still didn't work in the end after making all of those changes).

Ultimately, all I did was take the offending bit of Javascript (it was only one small function) and moved it to its own Javascript that does not get processed by Babel.

```php
// The code that gets processed fine is here:
mix.babel('public/js/stripe.js', 'public/js/processed/stripe.js')
// The code that doesn't get processed without error is here:
.copy('public/js/stripeUnminified.js', 'public/js/processed/stripeUnminified.js');
```

Considering the time I had invested, this workaround was an *ok* solution. Running the offending bit of Javascript through a compiler such as Babel just wasn't actually a super critical priority considering all of the headache it was causing and time it was taking. It was looking like I was going to have to rework and update a **lot** of the project just to fix this one little problem (and still a fix was not guaranteed).